# Statistical Model Representation with ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, statistics, anova

I will ask my question with a study case and then I'll make my question more general.

---

Let's first import some libraries and create some data:

```
require(visreg)
require(ggplot2)    
y = c(rnorm(40,10,1), rnorm(20,11,1), rnorm(5,12,1))
x=c(rep(1,40), rep(2,20), rep(3,5))
dt=data.frame(x=x, y=y)
```

and run a linear regression of `y` on `x` and graph the data and the model with ggplot2

```
m1 = lm(y~x, data=dt)
ggplot(dt, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(formula = y~x, method="anova", data=dt)
```

[image]

Now I would like to consider my `x`variable as a nominal variable. So I slightly change my data and run the following model.

```
y = c(rnorm(40,10,1), rnorm(20,11,1), rnorm(5,12,1))
x=factor(c(rep(1,40), rep(2,20), rep(3,5))) # this line has changed!
dt=data.frame(x=x, y=y)
m2 = lm(y~x, data=dt)
```

How can I plot this model `m2` with ggplot2? And more globally how can I directly tell ggplot to consider the object `m2` in order to create representation of the model?

What I aim to do is the kind of things that can be done using the `visreg` package

```
visreg(m2)
```

[image]

So, is there any visreg-like solution for ggplot? something like

```
ggplot(..,aes(..)) + super_geom_smooth(model = m2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not much different from @rnso's idea. `geom_jitter()` adds more flavour. I also change the colour of median bar. Hope this helps you!

```
ggplot(data = m2$model, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_boxplot(fill = "gray90") + 
geom_jitter()  +
theme_bw() +
stat_summary(geom = "crossbar", width = 0.65, fatten = 0, color = "blue",
fun.data = function(x){return(c(y=median(x), ymin=median(x), ymax=median(x)))})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I realize seeing your answer that my question was very unclear. Sorry about that. I posted another question that correspond much more to what I was looking for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029608/directly-plot-a-statistical-model-with-ggplots).

Answer (score 1):

Following using boxplot is very similar to your desired graph:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x,y))+ geom_boxplot(aes(group=x), alpha=0.5)+ geom_jitter()
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps something like this will do too. `ggplot(data = m2$model, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter()`

Comment: @ jazzurro: Your solution works. Post it as an answer.

Comment: You may want to drop `geom_point()` if you add `geom_jitter()`. You are drawing the same points twice right now.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, `visreg` can now output a `gg` object:

```
visreg(m2, gg=TRUE)
```

[image]