# Directly plot a statistical model with ggplots

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, statistics

The package `visreg` allows to plot directly a statistical model which I find very convenient to check if anything gone wrong and to check if we understand correctly what the estimates mean. I would love to combine the functionality of `visreg` with the incredible flexibility of `ggplot`. I'd like to be able to directly call the model in a ggplot code line. Is this feasible (eventually by directly modifying the `visreg` function)?

---

For example:

```
require(visreg)
require(ggplot2)
y = c(rnorm(40,10,1), rnorm(20,11,1), rnorm(5,12,1))
x=factor(c(rep(1,40), rep(2,20), rep(3,5))) # this line has changed!
dt=data.frame(x=x, y=y)
m = lm(y~x, data=dt)
```

I'd like to be able to directly call the object `m` in a `ggplot` function in order to represent my statistical model `m`. With `visreg`, it simply is:

```
visreg(m)
```

[image]

The below code is NOT what I am looking for as it does not directly call the object `m`

```
 ggplot(dt, aes(x,y)) + 
          geom_boxplot(aes(group=x), alpha=0.5)+geom_jitter()
```

[image]

Comment: no. ggplot's input is a data frame. you can write a wrapper function which will directly take your model and return a ggplot

Comment: @rawr - I just looked at your `rawr` package.  You have some really cool stuff there (not related to this post, just a compliment). :)

Comment: See http://www.slideshare.net/hadley/model-visualisation-with-ggplot2

Comment: Seeing str(m) or ls.str(m), there is a data frame (m$model), which you can use as a data frame for ggplot.

Comment: @RichardScriven I didn't know this package. I will have a look. It looks interesting.

Comment: @jazzurro `ggplot2::fortify.lm` will create a "useful" data.frame from a linear model object

Comment: @RichardScriven thank you! I've been attempting to collect cool stuff from myself and others

Comment: and @mnel @Remi.b `fortify.lm` isn't exported so you would need to triple colon that: `ggplot2:::fortify.lm`

Comment: @rawr - `fortify.lm` is an unexported s3 method. Calling `fortify` will dispatch quite happily to `fortify.lm` (perhaps I could have been clearer)

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, `visreg` now supports `ggplot2` output:

```
visreg(m, gg=TRUE)
```

produces

[image]